# Windows Phone and big memory allocation

Tags: windows-phone-7, memory-management, chess

I want to play with an old code I wrote of a chess engine trying to port it on WPhone. My old code uses a very big hash structure ( a so called Transposition Table ) that is up to 20 mb. Is this requirement acceptable for a game working on WP7, ora have I to resort in using different structure ( there is this option, the one used when no big amount of memory where avaiable called Refutation Table ) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows Phone apps can allocate up to 90MB so it should be possible to use your structure. You'll just need to be very careful about how you use it and what else your app does.

Comment: ok, this is a precise answer I need. About how I'm using, this will be an enormous array that in my app was a big unmanaged array for performance reason. Unfortunately I can't have the same ( unsafe ) on wp7, can I ?

Comment: My tests show that u can allocate up to 280 MB of memory. 90 MB is a certification restriction for 256MB phones(as i know there are no such devices). Correct me if i'm wrong

Comment: @Belorus allocating more than 90MB is pointless as apps must run on all devices. If the device only has 256MB then the app will be terminated when it uses over 90MB.

Comment: As i said there are no 256 MB devices. So currently u can use much memory. If devices with 256mb appear - u can write version 2.0 which will bring smaller functionality for such devices. U can add check whether device has 256mb and use less smart algorithm. Microsoft states that u should use <90mb for devices with 256 mb RAM. This restriction doesn't apply to 512mb devices.